# C++ passing by value semantics with copy/move

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am trying to understand move is not preferred in the following code. Does it only work with trivial constructors? Without side effect how does one test this?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct A {
  A() {cout << "A default constructor called." << endl;}
  A(const A &a);
  A(A &&a) {cout << "A move constructor called." << endl;}
  ~A() {cout << "A destructor called." << endl;}
};
// making sure inlining isn't the problem.
A::A(const A &a) {cout << "A copy constructor called." << endl;}

struct B {
  A a_;
  B(A a) : a_{a} {}
};

int main() {
  cout << "Testing copy elision when passing by value through B constructor." << endl;
  B b = A();
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output. Chained copy elision doesn't go through a constructor initializer even though the body does not use the argument?

```
Testing copy elision when passing by value through B constructor.
A default constructor called.
A copy constructor called.
A destructor called.
A destructor called.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you want a move you need `B(A a) : a_{std::move(a)} {}`.

Comment: Well B was called with a rvalue. I am surprised that seems to be lost even with an empty constructor.

Comment: `a` is an lvalue in `B`'s converting constructor. There's no special rule to make it "like an rvalue" in this case.

Comment: I read comments about how passing by value may be preferred now. I just want to understand under exactly what conditions that may be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "C++ Programming Language (Fourth Edition)", on move's:

"In a few cases, such as for a return value, the language rules say that it can (because the next action is defined to destroy the element). However, in general we have to tell it by giving an rvalue reference argument".

You have to specify the move in this case:

```
  B(A a) : a_{std::move(a)} {}
```